# Unable to ssh VM after hardware configuration change

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, gcloud

I followed the recommandation to reduce the size of my VM (number of CPU from 4 to 2 and memory from 16GO to 8 Go). After updating the configuration and restarting the VM i was not able to access the VM via ssh.
The VM has an external IP.
The troublshoot diagnostic using gcloud does not show any error or issue in the log. Everything is fine regarding the firewall configuration.

I tried to create a new VM under my project (same project as the original VM). I cannot access it with ssh. If i create a new project and a new VM instance under this new project then I can ssh it. --> The problem seems to be related to the project itself.

I tried to access vie serial port and I am getting these errors:

Mar  8 20:31:11 myvm systemd[1]: Started Google OSConfig Agent.

Mar  8 20:32:11 myvm OSConfigAgent[1173]: 2022-03-08T20:32:11.5643Z OSConfigAgent Critical main.go:100: Error parsing metadata, agent cannot start: network error when requesting metadata, make sure your instance has an active network and can reach the metadata server: Get http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/?recursive=true&alt=json&wait_for_change=true&last_etag=0&timeout_sec=60: dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: network is unreachable

Mar  8 20:32:11 myvm systemd[1]: google-osconfig-agent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Mar  8 20:32:11 myvm systemd[1]: google-osconfig-agent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Mar  8 20:32:12 myvm systemd[1]: google-osconfig-agent.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Mar  8 20:32:12 myvm systemd[1]: google-osconfig-agent.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.

I am blocked... I am asking for your support. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: 1) Double check the network adapter configuration in the GUI. 2) Verify that a service account is attached to the instance. 3) Resize back to the original configuration. 5) Snapshot the disk and try creating a new VM. 4) If none of those steps help, you might need Google Cloud Support to help you.

Comment: none of these steps are working unfortunately. Even creating a new vm under this project, I cannot access it.

Comment: If you understand the internals of Linux, connect via the serial port and debug, otherwise, I think you will need to open a support ticket with Google Cloud.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. However, accessing via serial port seems not possible (see error message). If I can only have access to the OS, I think I can debug it quickly.

Comment: Did you press Enter when accessing the serial console? No login prompt appears until you press Enter. It will just show the latest serial logs.

Comment: yes of course. I finished by removing completely the VM and creating a new one.